# Change the TFVC mapping folder without downloading the code again

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc

I have accidentally mapped the code branch in wrong folder. Is there a way to change the TFVC mapping folder without downloading the code over again.

Comment: Is tf get /remap command helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf get /remap` command, which will move the code from original folder to new folder:

[image]

More information, you can refer to the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command